# How to remove non Ascii characters(non keyboard special charecters) from a text in hive

Tags: regex, hive, ascii, hql

I want to remove non Ascii characters from my text and replace it with ''.

I have some invalid characters in my table that I'm trying to remove. But I ran into a problem with one of them.

Example:

```
123Abh¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½v streeÁÉÍÓt
```

Expected output:

```
123Abh street
```

As of now I'm using

```
regex_replace('123Abh¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½v streeÁÉÍÓt','[^[:print:]],'')
```

but this is not working, any suggestions?

Comment: What about `'[^\\x{0000}-\\x7D]+'`

Comment: Thank you it is working!!
@wiktor Stribizew  What if i need to remove all special characters apart from spaces and hyphens in hive.how will be the regrelpace statement?. thankyou in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
regex_replace('123Abh¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½v streeÁÉÍÓt', '[^\\x{0000}-\\x7E]+', '')
```

Here,

- `[^` - start of a negated character class that matches any chars but

  - `\x{0000}-\x7E` - chars from `NULL` to `~` char in the ASCII table
- `]+` - end of the class, match one or more times.

*What if I need to remove all special characters apart from spaces and hyphens*? - In this case, you need to use

```
regex_replace('123Abh¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½v streeÁÉÍÓt', '[^\\w\\s-]|_', '')
```

Here, `[^\w\s-]|_+` matches any one symbol other than letter, digit, `_`, whitespace and `-`, or an underscore (note `\w` matches underscores, thus it must be added via a `|`, an alternation operator).

Comment: Thankyou Wiktor it is working.!!

Need a help in one requirement.

1. In a string i want to replace everything apart from (0-9,A-Z,a-z,-,_)  with ''
2. In a string replace everything apart from 0-9(zero to nine) with ''
Appreciate your help!

Comment: @ap23451 If it is working, please consider accepting the answer (by clicking the grey tick on the left). 1) `[^0-9A-Za-z_-]` replace with `"`. 2) `[^0-9]` replace with `"`.

Comment: I Have accepted the answer.. can you please help me with below problem:
1. In a string i want to replace everything apart from (0-9,A-Z,a-z,-,_) with '' 2. In a string replace everything apart from 0-9(zero to nine) with ''
3.  In a string i want to replace everything apart from (0-9,A-Z,a-z,-,_) and spaces with ''
Thanks in Advance

Comment: @ap23451 Points 1 and 2 are already explained in the previous comment. 3) `[^0-9A-Za-z -]` and replace with whatever you need.

Comment: Hi Wiktor Thanks for all the help here.. 
I have the similar data set in hive but i just only want to replace tab and whitespace characters with single quotes..how can i do that?

Comment: @ap23451 You can try `regex_replace(..., '[ \t]+', '\'')`